# Configure iptables on linux ubuntu to route only specific IP between two networks

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing

I'm not a linux expert and I need to setup this scenario.

I've an Hyper-V host where I have two virtual network interfaces, both of them are added to a linux ubuntu machine, eth0 and eth1.

Now I have a bunch of Windows machines on the network eth1, and I've configured them to use ubuntu machine as gateway. Now I want the windows machines on the internal network to **access only a couple of Machines on eth0**.

This is base configuration I've setup

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Now all machine in eth1 can access all machines in eth0 and all machines from eth0 can access all machines in eth1.

What I need now is blocking eth1 traffic to eth0 except to two IP (Domain controllers) while it is good for me that all machines in eth0 can access machine in eth1.

What configuration should I do to iptables to block all traffic from eth1 to eth0 except to a bunch if IP?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
I've managed it to work with this configuration, it seems to works well but I'd like some comment if it is wrong or if there is a better solution.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state  --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.0.0.42 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the source IP address or subnet with the parameter "-s" and then drop all the traffic from eth1 to eth0

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.1 -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j DROP
```

Comment: My eth0 network is 10.0.0.0/24 while eth1 is 10.1.0.0/24 and I need that all the machine in 10.1.0.0/24 are able to access only 10.0.0.42 and no other machine in 10.0.0.0/24 but they should be able to access the internet and everything else. I've not managed the above configuration to work, but probably I've missed something.

Comment: I don't know which is your current default policy for the Chain FORWARD but if is set to DROP you only need to add the rule for allow access from 10.1.0.0/24 to 10.0.0.42 like that "iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.1.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.42/32 -j ACCEPT"